# What is the Wigner function of a thermal state?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

I am wondering how you would compute the Wigner Function of a Thermal State with
average phonon number $\bar{n}_{\mathrm{th}}$.
I know the result should be a Gaussian with variance in position $\langle x^2\rangle = (2 \bar{n}_\mathrm{th}+1) x_\mathrm{zp}^2$ and in momentum $ \langle p^2\rangle = (2 \bar{n}_\mathrm{th}+1) \hbar/(4x_\mathrm{zp}^2)$.

But how do I show that?

I write the thermal density matrix in the Fock basis:
\begin{equation}
\rho_\mathrm{th} = \sum_n \frac{\bar{n}_\mathrm{th}^n}{(1+\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})^{n+1}}|n\rangle \langle n | 
\end{equation}
and use the Wigner Tranform:
\begin{equation}
W_\mathrm{th}(x,p) = \int du \langle x- u/2 | \rho_\mathrm{th} | x + u/2 \rangle e^{\mathrm{i} p u/\hbar} 
\end{equation}

After inserting the density matrix into the Wigner transform I get:
\begin{equation}
W_\mathrm{th}(x,p) = \sum_n \frac{\bar{n}_\mathrm{th}^n}{(1+\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})^{n+1}} \int du \langle x- u/2  |n\rangle \langle n  | x + u/2 \rangle e^{\mathrm{i} p u/\hbar} = \sum_n \frac{\bar{n}_\mathrm{th}^n}{(1+\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})^{n+1}} W_n(x,p),
\end{equation}
where $W_n(x,p)$ is the Wigner functions of the n-Fock state given by:

\begin{equation}
W_n(x,p) = \frac{2}{\hbar \pi}(-1)^n e^{-2 \frac{H}{\hbar \omega} } L_n(4 \frac{H}{\hbar \omega} ),
\end{equation}
with $H= \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 + \frac{p^2}{2 m}$, and $L_n$ the nth Laguerre poloynomial.

Everything correct until here?

Now I am too stupid to do the last sum. Was looking for identities and what not half of this day.

Any ideas? I would also appreciate a simpler solution. Thanks for any Help!

Comment: You do know that the suitably scaled Laguerre polynomials, like their cousins Hermite, are a complete set, no? You are comfortable with *their* generating function? I believe you should write it in your question itself.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, their property of being a complete set doesn't help me, since I have these n dependent prefactors. I will write down what I did in more detail. Honestly, I hoped that there would be an easier solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct Wigner function for the eigenstates is half yours, so take it to be 
\begin{equation}
W_n(x,p) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\hbar \pi} e^{- z/2} L_n(z ),
\end{equation}
where $z=4 H/\hbar\omega  $.

You *know* that, since the resolution of the identity *must* be
$$
\sum_n  W_n= \frac{1}{2\pi \hbar}=1/h,
$$
which, indeed, holds (trivially checkable)  by dint of the standard [generating function of the Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Recursive_definition,_closed_form,_and_generating_function), 
$$
\sum_n t^n L_n(z)= \frac{e^{-tz/(1-t)}} {1-t}  ~~.
$$

Your sum then readily collapses to 
$$
 \sum_n \frac{\bar{n}_\mathrm{th}^n}{(1+\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})^n} W_n(x,p)= 
\frac{e^{-z/2}}{\pi \hbar}  \sum_n \left (\frac{- \bar{n}_\mathrm{th}}{1+ \bar{n}_\mathrm{th}} \right )^n  L_n  (z) = \frac{ (1+\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})}{\pi \hbar  (1+2\bar{n}_\mathrm{th})} ~ e^{-z / 2 (1+2 \bar{n}_\mathrm{th}) } ,
$$
a gaussian in *x* and *p* with the requisite widths.

These are the basic maneuvers in [phase-space quantization](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf),  Thomas L. Curtright, David B. Fairlie, & Cosmas K. Zachos, *A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space*, World Scientific, 2014.

Comment: This is *such a very sweet* solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: in the last step of the last expression, could it be that the $1+n_{\text{th}}$ factor at the nominator is not supposed to be there? If I understand the notation and $z=2(x^2+p^2)$, the normalisation doesn't seem to match. Integrating in polar coordinates, we have $\int_0^\infty dr 2\pi r e^{-r^2/(1+2n)}= \pi(1+2n)$ (I'm defining $\zeta=x+ip$, so that $z=2|\zeta|^2$, and writing $r=|\zeta|$)

Comment: Sorry, I won't chase the normalizations... and I saw you altered the question's... Suffice it to say that the answer is the product of two Gaussians, in *x* and *p* respectively, so with  exponent $-(x^2+p^2)/(1+2\bar n_{th})$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos ah, yes, I see that's the reason. The probabilities for the thermal state were given incorrectly, so there is simply an additional $1+n_{\text{th}}$ factor in the denominator of the last equation.